# Java Android Libgdx characters start at slow speed and then gain speed

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So basically, when my characters spawn they start slow and then gain speed as they walk.

How can I make it So my characters will just start at normal speed?

Here is a video of what i mean
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ffq_j5Fsu8&feature=youtu.be

Also here is my source code of my Zombie.java

http://pastebin.com/BKM1reZC

Comment: Ermm ... is it just me or do you have black zombies on a black background?  :-)

Comment: The background isn't black? Look at the video.

Comment: Ah ... the movie link works now.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the zombies are starting out slowly because of one or both of the following:

- Creation of zombies in parallel to animating them is causing the animation to run slowly, due to contention at some level.
- A "warmup" effect due to JIT compilation (I'm not sure if this is plausible on Android, but it certainly would be for a classic Java platform) or something else.

Comment: Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: If it is the first cause, try creating all of the zombies before you start the animation.  I don't know if there is a fix for the second cause that would work in your case.